# Único conteúdo json entre []

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

Eu to com uma dúvida sobre um código que eu fiz usando scrapy para coletar dados e mandar para um arquivo json.

O problema é que a formatação do arquivo não está como costuma ser, por isso achei estranho, estou em dúvida se há um problema ou não.

Segue abaixo o codigo e o conteudo do arquivo :

```
[
{"uf": "AL", "area": "C\u00edvel", "juiz": "Henrique Gomes de Barros Teixeira\n", "partes": [{"nome": "Maria Edite dos Santos", "tipo": "Autora", "Advogado(s)": [{"nome": "Defensoria P\u00fablica do Estado de Alagoas", "tipo": "Defensor P"}]}, {"nome": "Hipercard Banco Multiplo S/A", "tipo": "R\u00e9u", "Advogado(s)": [{"nome": "Raoni Souza Drummond", "tipo": "Advogado"}, {"nome": "Eduardo Fraga", "tipo": "Advogado"}, {"nome": "Andrea Freire Tynan", "tipo": "Advogado"}]}, {"nome": "W. dos S. F.", "tipo": "Testemunha"}, {"nome": "P. V. R. de L.", "tipo": "Testemunha"}]}
]
```

CODIGO:

```
import scrapy

class TjalSpdrSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'tjal'
    allowed_domains = ['www2.tjal.jus.br/cpopg/']
    # url_path = www2.tjal.jus.br/cpopg/open.do
    start_urls = [
        'https://www2.tjal.jus.br/cpopg/show.do?processo.codigo=01000I1FT0000&processo.foro=1&processo.'
        'numero=0731425-82.2014.8.02.0001&uuidCaptcha=sajcaptcha_2976d855423340b4be91a23ff5add85d'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        table_partes = response.xpath('//table[@id="tableTodasPartes"]/tr[@class="fundoClaro"]')

        area = ''.join(response.xpath('//table[@class="secaoFormBody"]/tr[4]/td[2]/table/tr/td/text()').getall())
        juiz = response.xpath('//table[@class="secaoFormBody"]/tr[10]/td/span/text()').get()
        partes = []

        for dados in table_partes:
            tipo = dados.xpath('./td/span/text()').get().strip()[:-1]
            tipo_adv = dados.xpath('./td[2]/span[@class="mensagemExibindo"]/text()').get()
            nome = dados.xpath('./td[2]/text()').get().strip()
            advg = [{'nome': f'{adv}'.strip(),'tipo': f'{tipo_adv}'.strip()[:-1]}
                    for adv in dados.xpath('./td[2]/text()[preceding-sibling::span]').getall() if adv.strip() != '']
            if nome != '':
                if tipo != 'Testemunha':
                    partes.append({
                        'nome': nome,
                        'tipo': tipo,
                        'Advogado(s)': advg
                        })
                else:
                    partes.append({
                        'nome': nome,
                        'tipo': tipo,
                    })

        yield {
               'uf': 'AL',
               'area': area.strip(),
               'juiz': juiz,
               'partes': partes
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Se a questão é apenas formatar a saída do json. A solução é usar o método `dumps()` da biblioteca `json`.

Veja abaixo:

```
>>> import json

>>> meu_json = [ {"uf": "AL", "area": "C\u00edvel", "juiz": "Henrique Gomes de Barros Teixeira\n", "partes": [{"nome": "Maria Edite dos Santos", "tipo": "Autora", "Advogado(s)": [{"nome": "Defensoria P\u00fablica do Estado de Alagoas", "tipo": "Defensor P"}]}, {"nome": "Hipercard Banco Multiplo S/A", "tipo": "R\u00e9u", "Advogado(s)": [{"nome": "Raoni Souza Drummond", "tipo": "Advogado"}, {"nome": "Eduardo Fraga", "tipo": "Advogado"}, {"nome": "Andrea Freire Tynan", "tipo": "Advogado"}]}, {"nome": "W. dos S. F.", "tipo": "Testemunha"}, {"nome": "P. V. R. de L.", "tipo": "Testemunha"}]} ]

>>> print(json.dumps(meu_json, indent=2))
```

A saída será:

```
[
  {
    "uf": "AL",
    "area": "C\u00edvel",
    "juiz": "Henrique Gomes de Barros Teixeira\n",
    "partes": [
      {
        "nome": "Maria Edite dos Santos",
        "tipo": "Autora",
        "Advogado(s)": [
          {
            "nome": "Defensoria P\u00fablica do Estado de Alagoas",
            "tipo": "Defensor P"
          }
        ]
      },
...
]
```

**Nota** Não coloquei toda a saída no post propositalmente para não deixá-lo extenso.

Entretanto se a questão é a acentuação, você pode usar a conversão com o parâmetro `ensure_ascii=False`.

```
>>> str_json = json.dumps(meu_json, ensure_ascii=False)

>>> print(str_json)

[{"uf": "AL", "area": "Cível", "juiz": "Henrique Gomes de Barros Teixeira\n", "partes": [{"nome": "Maria Edite dos Santos", "tipo": "Autora", "Advogado(s)": [{"nome": "Defensoria Pública do Estado de Alagoas", "tipo": "Defensor P"}]}, {"nome": "Hipercard Banco Multiplo S/A", "tipo": "Réu", "Advogado(s)": [{"nome": "Raoni Souza Drummond", "tipo": "Advogado"}, {"nome": "Eduardo Fraga", "tipo": "Advogado"}, {"nome": "Andrea Freire Tynan", "tipo": "Advogado"}]}, {"nome": "W. dos S. F.", "tipo": "Testemunha"}, {"nome": "P. V. R. de L.", "tipo": "Testemunha"}]}]
```

Claro que você pode combinar os dois

```
>>> print(json.dumps(meu_json, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2))
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: A questao é que tenho que lançar os dados pelo yield executando o spider usando 'scrapy crawl <spider> -o <nomedoarquivo>.json', e nesse arquivo o conteudo ta indo tudo em uma linha. Tentei lancar um yield com json.dumps como vc falou mas da o seguinte erro:  ERROR: Spider must return request, item, or None, got 'str' in

Comment: Se o json está bem formatado, não vejo problema de estar em uma única linha. Tem algum erro sendo gerado?

Comment: Nao, era apenas essa duvida. Como recem comecei a estudar web scraping normalmente qnd eu tentava puxar os dados para um arquivo json ele vinha diferente, mas se nao tem problema tudo bem, obrigado!!